# "Birthday" vs "Date of birth" on a website form

Tags: word-choice

In a login form for a website, what expression would fit better for the date input field? **Birthday** or **Date of Birth**?

And why?

Comment: Date of Birth or Birth Date. Why? It sounds more professional. To ask about a birthday brings in associations of clowns and donkey tails and ice cream.

Answer (score 9):

In everyday language "**birthday**" is associated more with the ***anniversary* of the date of birth**.  When asked about it, a person may (or would likely) provide just the month and day, but not the year.

"***Date of birth***", however, is much more difficult to misinterpret.

Whether to capitalize "birth" in your User Interface is probably up to your UX designers.